# Android background service survive sleep and reconnect UI

Tags: java, android

I want to create an android service which interacts with UI. It will connect to an IP via TCP. When mobile is in sleep mode, it still should receive packets and wake up device and update UI of Activity accordingly.
Problem is, UI and service both should survive back button pressing (or even process killers). As far as I know services survives pressing back, how can I manage to re-bind (instead of re-creating service and binding) to already existing service (if exists)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check whether service is already running or not, if not you can start service

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)     getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MyServiceName.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

in above code **MyServiceName.class** is name of the service.

Comment: So if running, how to re-bind?